# Where is a teaming file that gives the runner type stored?

Tags: linux, networking, bonding

If you create a bond using modprobe bonding then a file is stored in /proc/net/bonding/ giving the details of the bond. Is there any equivalent file, giving the runner type, for teamd?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to answer this question exactly. /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts will often have this information for the bond but I have been able to create situations (using teamd, teamdctl and ip link to set up the bond) in which this isn't the case.

The solution I settled on to find the runner type was running `teamdctl dev <team> config dump`. However, I didn't manage to find out where the config produced by teamdctl was stored. Finding where that is kept is probably the best answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `team` kernel module does not provide a similar `/proc/net/` status file as the `bonding` module does. Instead, you must use the `teamdctl` command to query the current configuration.

In RHEL and distributions related to it, if you use the default runner type `roundrobin`, there will be no mention of the runner type in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<team>` file, because the JSON configuration displayed by `teamdctl <team> config dump` is actually generated dynamically from default values whenever the team is started, so no JSON needs to be stored.

Other distributions that don't have the `/etc/sysconfig/` directory will be using some other NetworkManager configuration storage back-end. In that case, check under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`: that's the storage location for NetworkManager's distribution-neutral configuration storage.

If your distribution is not using NetworkManager, but instead some other mechanism to store the network configuration (like Ubuntu's `/etc/netplan` or a minimal Debian installation's `/etc/network/interfaces`, then you'll need to investigate how they'll handle teaming. (If you have done that, feel free to edit this answer to add information.)

The most user-friendly way to change the runner type is probably using NetworkManager, e.g. with `nmcli`:

```
nmcli c mod <team> team.runner activebackup
```

This will cause the minimized non-default part of the `teamd` configuration JSON to be stored in `TEAM_CONFIG` variable of the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<team>` file. For example, the command above applied to a team previously created using default values will result in this line getting added to the team's configuration file:

```
TEAM_CONFIG="{ \"runner\": { \"name\": \"activebackup\" } }"
```

If you want to check the current state of the team, `teamdctl <team> state view` should output something that is more human-friendly than JSON.

If you are looking for something that could be easily checked by a monitoring system, then in `/sys/devices/virtual/net/<team>/` directory, the `operstate` file says `up` if the team as a whole can pass traffic, and `down` otherwise. In the `lower_<interface>/` sub-directories, there are similar files for individual team members. The `carrier` and/or `carrier_changes` files might be good candidates for monitoring too. But there does not seem to be anything that would clearly identify the runner type.